# django password_reset can not submit form

Tags: html, django, forms

I can not submit the forms if extends from top html,if i delete {% extends 'accounting/password_reset_base.html' %}, the form can submit and send email, please help to fix this, thanks

{% extends 'accounting/password_reset_base.html' %}
{% load static%}

{% block headertitle_password %}
    Forgot Your Password ?
{% endblock %}
{% block passwordbase %}

```
<div class="container">

    <md-card>
        <div class="container_password">
        <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <input id="id_email" maxlength="254" name="email" type="email" />
    </div>
            <button type="submit" >Reset my password</button>
</form>
        </div>
    </md-card>

</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Comment: try `include` instead of `extend`

Comment: thanks,just tried, but not works, any other idea?